# unable to solve a compilation error

Tags: scala

My function return the following type

```
def someFunction(a:String) = Future[Tuple2[Option[List[Tag]],Option[PagingState]]]
```

I am calling the function as follows:

```
val listOptionFuture = someFunction("some string")
```

I am unable to write `flatMap` logic for `listOptionFuture`. I have written the following but I am getting compilation error

```
listOptionFuture.flatMap((tagOption,pagingStateOption) => {  ... })
```

Is above the correct way to map values returned from the `Future`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The argument to `flatMap` that you've written is a 2-argument function. What you want is a 1-argument function that takes a Tuple2 (and could immediately pattern match it):

```
listOptionFuture.flatMap{ case (tagOption,pagingStateOption) => {  ... }}
```

Comment: depends on what `{ ...  }` is, no? It should itself be a `Future`?

Comment: It should, yes. But needing to return the correct type and needing to take the correct type as arguments are pretty separate issues.

Comment: Your comment about 2-argument function was helpful. I couldn't make your code work but this worked for me `listQuestionsOptionFuture.flatMap((f:Tuple2[Option[List[PracticeQuestionTag]],Option[PagingState]]) => {...}`. I don't know why your code didn't work